# Unpairing paired Bluetooth Device using reflection and calling "removeBond" method not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bluetooth

I am using removeBond method from BluetoothDevice class to unpair the device since a long time. But in most of the xiaomi devices, this is not working.

Check below code I am using:

```
            Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            Log.i("DeletePairedDeviceByNm", "Found Device:" +
                    device.getName() + ", Looking for:" + BDName + "\n");
             if ((device.getName().trim().equals(BDName.trim()))) {

                Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);

                Object value=m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
                if((boolean)value){
                    numberPairedDevicesDeleted++;
                }
            }
      }
```

And as per my knowledge, this is the only method available to "unpair" connected device.

Is there something else that can be used? Please provide me with some valuable feedback.

Thanks in advance!

Some tested devices are:

- Xiaomi Mi Mix 3
- Xiaomi Redmi Note 7
- Xiaomi Redmi 6A
- Xiaomi Mi Max 2

Comment: hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: Has someone got a solution for this?? I have seen that the "m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null) "returns false but I can't figure out how to unpair devices with Xiaomi.

Comment: Got to know one more thing about Xiaomi devices, unpair is only working with this method if earlier, both pairing and unpairing is done using the same application.(First pair and then upair)

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: This is the way it's getting handled with a large BLE device library that was last updated in early June of 2022: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/blob/e3eeeb82a742b45707a58ec72eb384ccf6db9620/ble/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/android/ble/BleManagerHandler.java#L786